# Подготовка данных для обработки с помощью LSTM

Tags: python, pandas, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Возник следующий вопрос:

Пытаюсь решить задачу классификации последовательности, имеется исходный набор данных о пользователях, которые выглядит примерно так

```
user  date  feat_1  feat_2  feat_3 ... feat_n  label
  1     1      a       aa     12        144      0
  1     2      b       bb     13        189      1
  1     3      c       cc     12        143      0
  2     1      b       ab     16        195      0
  2     2     ...     ...    ...        ...     ...
```

Можно сказать, что существует некая последовательность действий, приводящая к определенной цели (target). Идея состоит в том, чтобы обучить нейросеть распознавать последовательность действий и предсказывать вероятность принадлежности этой последовательности к 0 или 1 классу.

Как правильно подготовить данные для LSTM сети? Ведь если подать всю на вход, то тогда не сохранится последовательность действий, а будет предсказываться отдельная транзакция?

Возможно, существует какой-то способ подать на вход сети многомерный массив, или существует какая-то эвристика, как представлять данные в подобном случае ?

Пытался сделать так: `X_train.groupby('user').agg(lambda x: list(x))`, но такой тип данных не понравился Keras.

Comment: LSTM ожидает на вход 3D тензор

Answer (score 0):

*Я совершенно не специалист*
На основе тех данных, что Вы представили, мне кажется, что использовать LSTM на всех признаках не стоит. Признаки не связаны мужду собой по времени и ,если Вы поменяете их местами, ничего не изменится. Опять же еще раз отмечу, что не знаю полных условий задачи.

**Что можно сделать:**
 **1. Задача классификации** - можно использовать обычную нейросеть или RandomForest или GradBoost (в принципе любую модель для классификации)
 **2.** Самое главное тут **подготовка данных**. Посмотреть какие признаки являются численными, а какие категориальными и обработать каждые, соответсвенно. Строчный тип здесь корее всего будет категориальным, но надо смотреть.
 **3.** Все признаки зависят от user and date. Здесь можно использовать **агрегацию признаков по времени**. И как раз учтете влияние времени на данные

Comment: "Я совершенно не специалист" - зачем это предисловие или что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Хотелось акцентировать внимание на том, что это не профессиональное мнение, а любительское.